# Error when creating ServiceBus Queue using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration

Tags: c#, .net, azure, servicebus

I am (trying) to use this code to create ServiceBus Queue:

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration;
...
class blabla
{
   private string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://XXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=XXXYYY";
   private string queueName = "testqueue";
   ...
   public doit()
   {
    var adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);
    bool queueExists = adminClient.QueueExistsAsync(queueName).Result;
    if (!queueExists)
    {
        var options = new CreateQueueOptions(queueName)
        {
            DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(2),
            LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45),
            MaxDeliveryCount = 8,
            MaxSizeInMegabytes = 2048
        };
        options.AuthorizationRules.Add(new SharedAccessAuthorizationRule(
            "allClaims",
            new[] { AccessRights.Manage, AccessRights.Send, AccessRights.Listen }));
        QueueProperties createdQueue = adminClient.CreateQueueAsync(options).Result;
    }

   }
}
```

but constantly getting this error:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (SubCode=40900. Conflict. You're requesting an operation that isn't allowed in the resource's current state. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions. . TrackingId:bc79fd98-73c8-4301-b6b9-05d0eae6ed6a_G17, SystemTracker:xxx.servicebus.windows.net:yyy, Timestamp:2021-05-09T00:24:57
Status: 409 (Conflict)
ErrorCode: 40900
```

Using old (NET) way with **NamespaceManager** from *Microsoft.ServiceBus* works with no problems.

```
  var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
  if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists(queueName))
  {
     namespaceManager.CreateQueue(queueName);
  }
```

So, does anyone knows what am I doing wrong here?
*

Comment: was the problem solved?

Comment: yes, the problem has been solved. Look at my last comment on this thread,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion.
My code (and Rahul Shukla as well) is working now.
I had to create a few new shared access policies with full access.
The third created started working.
The previous 2 I created are still not working.
There are no differences between the 3 policies created. Hence the question marks in my answer.
Posted question on MS NET SB forum about 1 out of 3 policies working. No answer/acknowledgment so far.

Comment: any more news regarding this issue? can you share the posted question in SB forum here for tracking? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Below is the updated working code, you need to  make sure you have shared access policy with full access.

[image: shared Access policies]

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ServiceBusDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://ns-servicebusshu.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=fullAccess;SharedAccessKey=oB+IsK8Aqp0/xfXnF9HCz6x9pqPIOysTXaJofSmHEYs=";
        private static string queueName = "testqueue";

        async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await doit();
        }
       
        public static async Task doit()
        {
            var adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);
            bool queueExists = await adminClient.QueueExistsAsync(queueName);

            if (!queueExists)
            {
                var options = new CreateQueueOptions(queueName)
                {
                    DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(2),
                    LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45),
                    MaxDeliveryCount = 8,
                    MaxSizeInMegabytes = 2048
                };
                options.AuthorizationRules.Add(new SharedAccessAuthorizationRule("allClaims", new[] { AccessRights.Manage, AccessRights.Send, AccessRights.Listen }));

                QueueProperties createdQueue = await adminClient.CreateQueueAsync(options);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Once you ran the application its successfully created the queue as below :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is exactly the setup I have. Result is same error:
Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: SubCode=40900. Conflict. You're requesting an operation that isn't allowed in the resource's current state. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions. . TrackingId:7018f8f0-6624-4346-a1ea-60832e64a8a8_G4, SystemTracker:xxx.servicebus.windows.net:testq, Timestamp:2021-05-09T14:38:03
Status: 409 (Conflict)
ErrorCode: 40900

Comment: @Kajko Are you trying multiple request at the same time ? Can you try with the above code and try with single request. It should work. I have tried the same and its working perfectly

Comment: My code (and Rahul as well) is working now (????). I had to create a few new shared access policies with full access (????). The third created started working (??). The previous 2 I created are not working still (????). There is no differences between the 3 policies created. Hence the question marks in my answer. Posted question on MS NET SB forum about 1 out of 3 policies working. No answer/aknowledgment so far.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not your case... But if you have a TOPIC with the same name that you try to create your new QUEUE, QueueExistsAsync will return `false`, but you'll be spitted with this bizarre error at creation time. The fix is easy... changing the queue name or deleting the offending topic.