# Azure Service Bus - How to Add Topic Subscriber Programmatically

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, .net-5

I'm trying to implement a basic pub/sub system with dynamic subscribers. I need to dynamically register a topic subscriber in my .NET APIs, but it seems like I can only do that manually from the Azure Portal. When my program starts, I want to be able to register a subscriber to a topic in the format of `subscribername-{timestamp}` because I want to be able to deploy as many staging/dev versions as I want without having to manually create these subscribers each time.

I feel like this is a fundamental feature that I'm just blindly missing. I can do this when working with queues, but if I try to do the same with a topic, I get continuous errors of that subscriber path not found. I have searched the internet to no end and while I have found SOME solutions, they are very old and often not compatible with .NET 5 or the package is deprecated. I'm feeling like I'm going against the grain and missing something with what I'm coming up with, so I'd like to get some input on what the proper practice is for this.

I'm using `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` for publishing and subscribing currently. Below is some code -

```
var processor = ServiceBusClient.CreateProcessor(TopicName, $"DynamicSubscriber-{DateTime.Now}");
    
try
{
    processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;
    processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
    await processor.StartProcessingAsync();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    await processor.DisposeAsync();
    await ServiceBusClient.DisposeAsync();
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Use the [ServiceBusAdministrationClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient?view=azure-dotnet) class

Comment: @PeterBons Really not sure how I didn't see this. You're a life saver. Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 0):

Thank You @PeterBons! Yes, when updating/creating/fetching/deleting the Service Bus entities, [ServiceBusAdministrationClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient?view=azure-dotnet) is the client Class to be used.

Also, There are few error details given this [article](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/javascript/azure-service-bus/7.0.0-preview.6/classes/servicebusadministrationclient.html) when using the method of Queue with ServiceBusAdministrationClient and this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67453341/error-when-creating-servicebus-queue-using-azure-messaging-servicebus-administra).

The **ServiceBusTopicSubscription** class is used to setup the Azure Service bus subscription. The class uses the **ServiceBusClient** to set up the message handler, the **ServiceBusAdministrationClient** is used to implement filters and add or remove these rules. The **Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus** Nuget package is used to connect to the subscription.